# Code explanation

Tags: java

Given these set of instructons am I right in saying that :

1) Here I declare two list objects called : audiobytes and lines

```
List<Byte> audioBytes;
List<Line2D.Double> lines;
```

2) Here I empty the lists  created in step 1 , and update the component --> repaint()

```
public void resetWaveform() {
    audioBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Double>();
    repaint();
}
```

3) Here unfortunately I don't understand:

```
public void createWaveForm() {
    // what does it mean ????
    if (audioBytes.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

What puzzles me is that the method is called createWaveForm but actually does nothing..is
 that correct?

Comment: please don't flag your posts with terms like "urgent" or "asap": people answer quickly enough, besides, by doing so, one might interpret that you think your questions are more important than other people's questions.

Answer (score 1):

1) Correct

2) Almost. I would create lists in #1 and then call `clear()` on each. Simply because dealing with nulls is a nightmare

3) It does nothing only when list of audio bytes has no data. I guess there is more code after the if statement

Comment: unless `size()` has side-effects ;)

Comment: on ArraysList? What kind of side effects?

Comment: @aioobe: `ArrayList.size()` is free of side-effects. Google finds the source dead easy; check for yourself.

Comment: @Donal: Maybe he hacked his SDK and put the main logic for his program in the `ArraysList.size()` method.

Comment: In #3 there is no more code..that's the problem.
So what's the use of creating a method which does nothing..
The side-effects you talk about , are they feasible?
I mean if I use a list that means that it can be adjustable in size ..right?

Answer (score 1):

You did not empty the lists in step 2, you threw them away and created 2 new lists. This is *not* the same if something is still holding a reference to the old lists. You should use the `clear()` method instead.

As far as your code in part 3, yes it really does nothing (except needlessly check the size), assuming you haven't cut anything out. If there was something else there, then all that segment of code is saying is "if there is no data, return (don't execute anything more)".